# ORDER BY before a Collect and With

Tags: php, neo4j, cypher

I have a large Cypher query in which I gather a number of pieces of information for a view in my app. At one part I use an OPTIONAL MATCH to get upcoming meetups but I need them order by ASC before they go into a COLLECT and passed forward with a WITH statement. I tried to add it below the WHERE clause by, obviously, it's throwing an error.

Is there a way to order by in a OPTIONAL MATCH or in a COLLECT statement?

Here is my Cypher query

```
MATCH (o:Person)<-[:OWNED_BY]-(g:Group {group_slug:"'.$group_slug.'"})<-[:MEMBER_OF]-(m:Person)-[:JOB_TITLE]->(title:Title)
WITH o,g,COLLECT({first_name: m.first_name, last_name: m.last_name, image_name: m.image_name, username: m.username, job_title: title.job_title}) as members,title,COUNT(m) as member_count
OPTIONAL MATCH (g)-[:TOPIC_OF]->(t:Topic)
WITH o,members,g,COLLECT(DISTINCT t.name) as topics,title,member_count
OPTIONAL MATCH (g)-[:CREATED]->(mu:Meetup{status:"Active"})-[:MEETUP_AT]->(l:Location)
WHERE toInt(mu.meet_date) >= '.time().'
WITH o,members,g,title,topics,COLLECT({location_name:l.location_name, address:l.address,city:l.city,state:l.state,zip_code:l.zip_code,meet_date:mu.meet_date,meeting_id:id(mu)}) as meetups,member_count
OPTIONAL MATCH (g)-[]->(amu:Meetup)
WITH o,members,g,title,topics,meetups,COUNT(amu) as meetup_count,member_count
OPTIONAL MATCH (g)<-[:REQUESTED]-(pm:Person)-[:JOB_TITLE]->(pmt:Title)
WITH o,members,g,title,topics,meetups,meetup_count,COLLECT({first_name: pm.first_name, last_name: pm.last_name, image_name: pm.image_name, username: pm.username, job_title: pmt.job_title}) as requested,member_count
OPTIONAL MATCH(g) <-[:FAVORITED]-(fp:Person)
WITH o,members,g,title,topics,meetups,meetup_count,requested,COUNT(fp) as favorited,member_count
RETURN o.username as owner_username, o.first_name as owner_first, o.last_name as owner_last, g.group_name as group_name, g.description as description, g.access as access, g.group_slug as group_slug,
topics, members,meetups,meetup_count, favorited,requested,member_count
```

where the offending query part is

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (g)-[:CREATED]->(mu:Meetup{status:"Active"})-[:MEETUP_AT]->(l:Location)
WHERE toInt(mu.meet_date) >= time()
```

Comment: What is the error message? Also, note that the timestamp function is `timestamp()` not `time()`.

Comment: The time() is PHP. Sorry i didn't specify that

Answer (score 0):

[Edited]

A `WITH` clause can be followed by `ORDER BY`, `SKIP`, and `LIMIT` clauses.

Does this query work for you?

```
WITH timestamp() AS now
MATCH (o:Person)<-[:OWNED_BY]-(g:Group {group_slug:"'.$group_slug.'"})<-[:MEMBER_OF]-(m:Person)-[:JOB_TITLE]->(title:Title)
WITH o,g,COLLECT({first_name: m.first_name, last_name: m.last_name, image_name: m.image_name, username: m.username, job_title: title.job_title}) as members,title,COUNT(m) as member_count
OPTIONAL MATCH (g)-[:TOPIC_OF]->(t:Topic)
WITH o,members,g,COLLECT(DISTINCT t.name) as topics,title,member_count
OPTIONAL MATCH (g)-[:CREATED]->(mu:Meetup{status:"Active"})-[:MEETUP_AT]->(l:Location)
WHERE mu.meet_date >= now
WITH o,members,g,topics,title,member_count,mu,l
ORDER BY mu.meet_date
WITH o,members,g,title,topics,COLLECT({location_name:l.location_name, address:l.address,city:l.city,state:l.state,zip_code:l.zip_code,meet_date:mu.meet_date,meeting_id:id(mu)}) as meetups,member_count
OPTIONAL MATCH (g)-[]->(amu:Meetup)
WITH o,members,g,title,topics,meetups,COUNT(amu) as meetup_count,member_count
OPTIONAL MATCH (g)<-[:REQUESTED]-(pm:Person)-[:JOB_TITLE]->(pmt:Title)
WITH o,members,g,title,topics,meetups,meetup_count,COLLECT({first_name: pm.first_name, last_name: pm.last_name, image_name: pm.image_name, username: pm.username, job_title: pmt.job_title}) as requested,member_count
OPTIONAL MATCH(g) <-[:FAVORITED]-(fp:Person)
WITH o,members,g,title,topics,meetups,meetup_count,requested,COUNT(fp) as favorited,member_count
RETURN o.username as owner_username, o.first_name as owner_first, o.last_name as owner_last, g.group_name as group_name, g.description as description, g.access as access, g.group_slug as group_slug,
topics, members,meetups,meetup_count, favorited,requested,member_count;
```

For efficiency, we first create a `now` variable, instead of recalculating the current time every time we need it. This will also ensure consistent results:

```
WITH timestamp() AS now
```

The `WHERE` clause in the "offending" query part has been replaced by:

```
WHERE mu.meet_date >= now
WITH o,members,g,topics,title,member_count,mu,l
ORDER BY mu.meet_date
```

Comment: The order by now works but can I still only pull dates greater than or equal to today?